# Insertion sort task

Tags: c++, sorting, insertion-sort

I was trying to solve a problem in which I should sort increasingly array of numbers, than take first k numbers from sorted array and eliminate those numbers that are repeating and write them on the output.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n, k;
cin >> n >> k;
int tab[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //taking n numbers from input
{
    cin >> tab[i];            
} 

int j, element;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) //i am using insertion sort
{
    j = 0;
    while (tab[j] < tab[i])
          j++;
    element = tab[i];
    for(int k = i - 1; k >= j; k--)
            tab[k + 1] = tab[k];
    tab[j] = element; 
}

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) //writing k smallest numbers without repetitions
{
    if (tab[i] == tab[i + 1])
       continue;
    cout << tab[i] <<"\n";    
}
cin >> n;
return 0;
}
```

generally it works and it gives expected output, however when I am uploading this problem to check its correctness (i found this problem on polish site), it says "wrong anwser".
I cannot see any errors here, maybe you will see something which I wrote bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the problem. 'eliminate those numbers that are repeating' means you have to print the number once and eliminate subsequent occurrence(s) of that number. For ex.

```
n = 5;
k = 3;
tab[n] = 5 1 1 1 1
```

Here, sorted tab[] becomes '1 1 1 1 5', then expected output is '1', but your program gives nothing!

I hope this helps :)